# Reversing Chebyshev inequality argument

Tags: philosophical, statistical-learning

One way one could state Chebyshev's inequality is

> The probability that a realization deviates from the mean more
>   than $k$ standard deviations is at most $\frac{1}{k^2}$.

My question is: Can one rigorously reverse this logic and make a statement about the probability that the actual mean is close to the observation. One immediate technical problem is that one needs to define a probability space on possible probability distributions/means.

I'm asking because I think this type of argument (although slightly more convoluted) underlies Vapnik-Chervonenkis theory.  In their textbooks this issue is not discussed at all. They prove a large deviation principle and then simply invert all their inequalities. How does this work?  Does it?

Comment: Not completely sure about what you mean by "reversing": Obviously $|X - \mu|$ is the same as $|\mu - X|$, where $\mu$ denotes true mean of $X$. In this way, the answer is "yes".

Comment: Very interesting, an extremely subtle question.  I think the point he is getting at @MichaelMayer is that although $|X-\mu|$ is numerically $|\mu-X|$ the distribution of $X|\mu$ is not the same as $\mu|X$.  My feeling is this either leads us into Bayesian statistics, where it will all fall out fine once you specify priors etc., or into those tortured lawyer-esque frequentist statements about exactly what a confidence intervals is.

Comment: @Corone: You are right, I didn't realize the Bayesian flavor of the question :-)

Comment: @Corone Yes, the question is can we argue about $\mu|X$ and what may be a suitable rigorous mathematical framework.  I'll not accept "Bayesian statistics" as an answer, that's too cheap :)

Comment: Suppose I observe the value $19.21886$ from an unknown distribution (which might be a Cauchy distribution of unknown centre and spread, or from something completely different).  I do not even know if the population distribution has a mean or standard deviation, so it is difficult to say much in general about how far the mean is from my observation.

Comment: If you do not assume a prior distribution for (mean, SD), then it is hard even to make sense of this question. (What does it mean to be "close"? What does it mean to talk about the "probability" of the mean?) So I do not think you can reject a Bayesian solution as "too cheap."

Comment: You need to clarify whether you are looking at $\mu|X$ (@Corone style and a comment of yours) or $\mu|x$ (@Henry style and the main body of the question)... and I won't accept "both" as an answer, that's too expensive (to answer). :)

Comment: @whuber I'm not rejecting a Baysian solution at all.  I'm rejecting just "Bayesian statistics solves this" as too unspecific for an answer.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos in Vapnik-Chervonenkis theory it's $\mu|x$ (that is, actual values, data).  Also, it is not Chebyshev's inqequality, but a large deviation type inequality that is inverted.  If you happen to have one of their books around, any of the results that starts with: "With probability $1-\delta$" I would call unfounded.